# Lazy load a directive into a component in a page IONIC 3

Tags: angular, ionic2, lazy-loading

I have a page that uses a component and in the template of that component I call a directive. I have imported the directive into a shared module that is that added to the page.module set up. But the directive is not registered on the component. How can I get this to work.

PAGE -> COMPONENT -> DIRECTIVE

Shared module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
/** Directives **/
import { CallDirective } from '../directives/call/call';
import { NavigateDirective } from '../directives/navigate/navigate';
import { OpenLinkDirective } from '../directives/open-link/open-link';
import { ShareDirective } from '../directives/share/share';
import {UserBookingsDirective} from '../directives/user-bookings/user-bookings'
import {BookingCommentDirective} from '../directives/booking-comment/booking-comment'
/** Pipes **/
import { LimitToPipe } from './../pipes/limit-to/limit-to';
import { SearchPipe } from './../pipes/search/search';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  CallDirective,
    NavigateDirective,
    OpenLinkDirective,
    ShareDirective,
    UserBookingsDirective,
    BookingCommentDirective,
    LimitToPipe,
    SearchPipe
  ],
  exports:[
      CallDirective,
    NavigateDirective,
    OpenLinkDirective,
    ShareDirective,
    UserBookingsDirective,
    LimitToPipe,
    SearchPipe
  ],
  imports: [

  ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Page Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BookingsPage } from './bookings';
import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';
import {SharedModule} from '../../app/shared.module';
/** Components **/
import {BookingItemComponent} from '../../components/booking-item/booking-item'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BookingsPage,
    BookingItemComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(BookingsPage),
    MomentModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
})
export class BookingsPageModule {}
```

Comment: Please show the code how you "imported" the directive.

Comment: I have added the code I use to import the modules, there you can see I have the directed imported into shared module

Comment: Adding the code that shows how you use the component and directive would also be helpful. From the available code it's not clear what component or directive you are referring to.

Comment: BookingCommentDirective I want to use that on a element in the component BookingItemComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `BookingCommentDirective` to `exports: [...]`, to make it available to importing modules:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  CallDirective,
    NavigateDirective,
    OpenLinkDirective,
    ShareDirective,
    UserBookingsDirective,
    BookingCommentDirective,
    LimitToPipe,
    SearchPipe
  ],
  exports:[
    BookingCommentDirective, // <<== added
    CallDirective,
    NavigateDirective,
    OpenLinkDirective,
    ShareDirective,
    UserBookingsDirective,
    LimitToPipe,
    SearchPipe
  ],
  imports: [

  ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```